# Search in mysql db with result containing string with partial match

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, partial

I need to create a powerful search page for my website, I am using php & mysql.

I want to

- get results with partial match. 
       Eg, if I have **stackoverflow** in db but i have searched **stacke** so that should show up in the results.

  I know about LIKE. I want to build a search like google which does take similar type words and searches that too.
- get results by matching every word in the search string separately.

Comment: Do you want to use the [full text search indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) of MySQL or an external search provider like [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)?

Comment: there is no part `stacke` in `stackoverflow`

Comment: @tadman - thanks for understanding the requirement buddy!
I want to build a search like google which does take similar type words and searches that too.

Comment: You'll probably need to look at a search add-on for MySQL. The built in tools are decent enough if you're willing to put up with their limitations. The add-ons vary in capability, from better to fantastic.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about "stacke" since that's not a substring of "stackoverflow". Maybe you meant "stacko"? In that case your query would be like

```
SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE field LIKE "stacko%";
```

Comment: I know about LIKE. Please read the question again, i have modified it.